# PySpark - UnpicklingError: NEWOBJ class argument has NULL tp_new

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

**When I am executing the bellow, I am getting Unpickling Error**

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('HOMICIDE', {'2017': 1}), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', {'2015': 2, '2017': 2, '2016': 8}), 
('ROBBERY', {'2016': 2})])

rdd.flatMapValues(dict.items).collect()
```

**The error is as bellow, Is there any issue on using flatMapValues on dictionay values**

```
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 422, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
UnpicklingError: NEWOBJ class argument has NULL tp_new
) [duplicate 3]
17/06/06 17:01:14 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('HOMICIDE', {'2017': 1}), 
                      ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', {'2015': 2, '2017': 2, '2016': 8}), 
                      ('ROBBERY', {'2016': 2})])

rdd.flatMapValues(lambda data: data.items()).collect()

[('HOMICIDE', ('2017', 1)),
 ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2015', 2)),
 ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2017', 2)),
 ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2016', 8)),
 ('ROBBERY', ('2016', 2))]
```

dict.items is method descriptor. You have to supply a function to inform flatmap how to unpack those values. I did that by passing in labmda function to the flatMap function.